# Expandable CardView using Cardslib

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardslib

I need to create cards that expand when a button on the card is pressed, to show additional features.

I'm planning to use : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

The guide is a bit confusing. Could someone please elaborate on how to go about. Also, the cards I show are populated by a RecyclerView.

I've attached screenshots of the required design below :

**Before expanding :**

[image]

**After expanding :**

[image]

Also, since the entire layout changes after expanding, I need the layout of the 'unexpanded' card to be hidden after the layout of the 'expanded' card becomes visible.

Any help would be awesome!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading this solves the problem : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDRECYCLERVIEW.md